# jqueryMobile datebox and webshim + checkValidity()

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, datebox, webshim

Im using [datebox](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/) and want some validation on my input if there isn't any value.

```
<input name="fromDate" id="fromDate" type="date" data-role="datebox" required = "" data-errormessage="error">
```

Im using webshim and it work great if I remove `data-role="datebox"`. 
Is their any way to make it work with datebox?

Comment: Would you be interested to use any other validation plugin?

Comment: If I goes on with another it will look on another way then it does by the default browser look that it is in HTML5. And I can build my own validation that look if its empty or not and fire a jQuery mobile popup or something that will look OK. But ofc link to the other plugins and I will check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a datebox issue with HTML5 formvalidation. datebox is setting the input to readonly, which means in HTML(5), that the field should not be validated (willValidate = false). If you remove the readonly attribute or set readOnly property to false, it works again.

Why don't you use webshims' datepicker (see some variations: http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/VNuct/).

```
$.webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext');
```

If you use type="date" you shouldn't use datebox, either unless you make it more HTML5 compatible (i. e. always yyyy-mm-dd format and so on)

The best thing here: You can replace UI in all desktop browsers and leave the native implementation in modern mobile browsers, which means, less code to download and execute. (But of course you can use styleable datepickers everwhere, if you want).

If you need a specific feature for the datepicker of webshims let me know.

Comment: I whould used webshims datepicker if jQM handle it better. Anyway, thanx for you answer! :)

Comment: btw, does webshim make the support for checkValidity() in older browsers?

Comment: Yes, webshims adds the full constraint validation API

Comment: fwiw, datebox does have the option "lockInput", which is true by default - set it to false, and datebox will not add the readonly attribute to the input.  Of course, datebox does specifically define the output format, but it does not have any way of checking pre-submit that the date is "valid" based off of your validation criteria, or even filled in at all.